# allow user to write for first attempt in firestore rules

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am in a peculiar situation right now. I am implementing an addFriend functionality. which adds the user to a collection named "friends" containing a document {uid} which is an array of friends {uid}.

Here is my Document structure:

[image: kuchbhi]

I want users to edit only their data so I have rule :

```
function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
 function isUser(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

match /friends/{userId} {
    allow read:if isSignedIn();
    allow create:if isSignedIn();
    allow update: if isSignedIn() && isUser(userId);
```

Now the security lapse is in create: Any user who is signed in can create, but I should be allowing people to create their own data. **I can do that by comparing the incoming document name with uid, but I am not sure how to do that.**

Here is code where I create or update friends collection:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FRIENDS).document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                    .update("friends", FieldValue.arrayUnion(scorecard.getUid()))
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) ;
                        else {
                            Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap();
                            m.put("friends", FieldValue.arrayUnion(scorecard.getUid()));
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FRIENDS).document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                                    .set(m);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I think your `isUser(userId)` function should also work for the `create`

Comment: @nVitius I cannot do that since, userId (i.e., document name) hasn't been created while inserting the first element.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the answer, If you need to check against the name of the incoming document you can use the rule

```
request.auth.uid==request.resource.__name__
```

You can further see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the `isUser` function you wrote for the create method.

I just tested this on the Firebase console's Rules Playground:
[image]

Unless I'm missing something, I believe this is what you're trying to do.

As a side note, you don't have to run `.update` and then `.set` if it failed.
You can use [`SetOptions.merge`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions#merge()) to do either update or create based on if the document exists.

```
Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap();
m.put("friends", FieldValue.arrayUnion(scorecard.getUid());
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
  .collection(FRIENDS)
  .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
  .set(m, SetOptions.merge())
```

`FieldValue.arrayUnion` will create the Array if it doesn't exist.